# Move upload file in php throwing error localhost

Tags: php, file, file-upload, upload

The file is not uploading can anyone explain how can I debug these errors.

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): The second argument to copy() function
>   cannot be a directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sanigo\my-account\Registerformcontroller.php on line
>   21

Second one:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move
>   'C:\xampp\tmp\phpEB06.tmp' to 'images/' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sanigo\my-account\Registerformcontroller.php on line
>   21

my code:

```
$dir = 'images/'
$file = $_FILES['fileinputname']['tmp_name'];

move_uploaded_file($file , $dir );
```

Comment: Please read the documentation http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php and the duplicate the question was closed with.

Comment: The missing quotes here `[tmp_name]` will throw you an error here, btw. Edit: this comment was based on the original post https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46404969/1 to which you just edited https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46404969/2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second argument of the `move_uploaded_file` needs to be a full path, including the file name.

For example:

```
$dir = 'images/'
$file = $_FILES['fileinputname'][tmp_name];
$new_file_name = 'foo.bar';

move_uploaded_file($file , $dir . $new_file_name);
```

Comment: But I have used without `filename` once it `worked` well. now it is saying like this when to use `full path with the file name` and when `the only directory` is sufficient

Comment: I guess there was something in that other case in the desitnation string what php could consider as filename. I can not tell unless you can share that code, but you will always need to include a filename.

Comment: okay thanks, i will accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

As the php.net said : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.move-uploaded-file.php

> bool move_uploaded_file ( string $filename , string $destination )

```
$dir = 'images/'
$file = $_FILES['fileinputname'][tmp_name];
$name = $_FILES["fileinputname"]["name"]
move_uploaded_file($file , "$dir/$name");
```